# How do I install a package with npm with a different/custom module name

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I want to install a specific revision from a github tarball named something like "mymodule" and name it something like "mymoduleTemp", and then load a potentially different version of it that will take the real name "mymodule".

So, how do I do the first thing? I'm looking for something like:

```
npm install https://github.com/me/mymodule/tarball/someTag -name mymoduleTemp
```

Is there any way to do that? A nice-to-have:

- If mymodule already exists, it doesn't get clobbered when mymoduleTemp is installed (ie ideally the process wouldn't be to install as mymodule then rename the folder)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there was an issue filed on the npm-github repository requesting that feature.

read on here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2943

Comment: I guess I just have to use only one version of a module, and then use a symlink to do the aliasing I want

Comment: dang, I have a use case for a project that pulls in another project specified by an environment variable, and it's the way I had planned on abstracting so that I could reference that project somewhere in the code.

Comment: I think it's a big shame they didn't provide this from the start.  Often I fork a package to fix a bug, then I have to build it and release it under `@myusername/packagename`.  I wish it were easy to install `@myusername/packagename` as `packagename` so I could get my bugfixes without having to change any `require` or `import` statements.

Comment: @BT yeah I think Isaac Schleuter wasn't very forward thinking when he made that Guido van Rossumesqe decision.

Comment: @Andy You can already do that by specifying an [URL as dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies).

Comment: @riezebosch oh, I didn't realize that, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @riezebosch still it's a shame that doesn't enable you to fork `somepackage`, fix something, publish it to npm as  `@myusername/somepackage`, then install it as `somepackage`... it would install as `@myusername/somepackage` instead.  But I guess running `npm pack`, copying the tarball to whatever server, and installing from that URL isn't too bad.

Comment: @Andy your case is now covered in `npm@6.9.0`, try `npm i somepackage@npm:@myusername/somepackage`

Answer (score 35):

In newer versions of npm (6+), its now possible to alias the module name with

```
npm i <alias_name>@npm:<original_package_name>
```

Comment: What does 'new' mean?

Comment: @roydukkey you need npm 6+ for this trick. this question was posted on 2013, while npm6 was officially introduced on April 2018. I posted my answer to help other people that run into the same problem I had

Comment: if you have already installed the package just change it to this:

`"<alias_name>": "npm:<original_package_name>@<version>",`

Comment: Hi @ShivamTiwari, in the `package.json`. find the original one. it looks like: `<original_package_name>:<version>`

Answer (score 32):

Since `npm@6.9.0` you could install package under a custom module name. `npm@6.9.0` [introduces support](https://npm.community/t/release-npm-6-9-0/5911) for package aliases.

To install a tarball under custom module name use `custom-name@tarball-url` argument, e.g. install specific `express` tarball as `my-express` module:

`npm i my-express@https://github.com/expressjs/express/archive/4.16.3.tar.gz`

This feature also allows to alias packages published to npm registry:

`npm i express@npm:@my-scope/express`

Comment: Looks like yarn has had this feature for a while now. I use yarn these days anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the upstream documentation for the syntax? Found out about this feature in the release notes but I couldn't figure out how to use it before this answer.

Comment: @Epeli I haven't found any mention about package aliasing in documentation. I learned how to use it from test cases which was added in feature pull request.

Comment: @PavelZubkou - I assume you mean 
> install specific express tarball as `myexp` module:
and not this: 
> install specific express tarball as `my-express` module:

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

1. Get the tarball and extract it
2. Change the `name` in its `package.json` to `@me/mymoduleTemp` (you could skip steps 1 and 3 by editing the tarball in place with `vim mymoduleTemp.tgz`)
3. Compress it to `mymoduleTemp.tgz`
4. Run `npm publish mymoduleTemp.tgz` (with `--access public` unless you want it to be restricted)
5. In your main project, run `npm install @me/mymoduleTemp`

I'd recommend publishing it as a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope), because if you publish it as unscoped `mymoduleTemp`, then no one else can use that name.

If you think even publishing scoped packages is polluting the npm registry, then you can just put the new tarball on your own private server (or in GitHub, or wherever) and install it via URL.

Comment: Mm, thanks for the workaround idea, but publishing something under another name isn't something I would want to do, nor is it scalable for anyone who wants to do this to be publishing dupes on npm.

Comment: If it's under your own scope, who cares?

Comment: @BT I added a note about hosting the tarball outside of the npm registry in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Specfically for browser you can add an alias in `package.json`

https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

eg:

```
{
  ....
  "browser": {
    "someTag": "mymoduleTemp"
  }
}
```

This also works for "react-native" with [metro](https://facebook.github.io/metro/) bundler. 
I've never tested with webpack bundles.