# install npm dep module in certain folder

Tags: git, npm, package.json

I have a module in git repo, and want to install it as dependency in package.json:

```
"my-module-dev": "git://github.com/user/my-module#dev",
```

But when I do `npm install` npm installes it in the `node_modules/my-module`, it is possible to make it install in `node_modules/my-module-dev`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a package with npm with a different/custom module name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127054/how-do-i-install-a-package-with-npm-with-a-different-custom-module-name)