# Importing scoped npm modules without scope name in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, npm, node-modules

We have some private NPM packages using npmjs' private repository. Assume

- scope name : `@scope`
- private package name as : `private-package`

When we install this NPM package using 
`npm install @scope/private-package`

It is installed to : `.node_modules/@scope/private-package`

In VSCode, to import some thing from this package, we need to do
`import {SomeThing} from '@scope/private-package'`

Is there anything in TypeScript configuration that we can re-map
`@scope/private-package` to `private-package` 
so that we can use like 
`import {SomeThing} from 'private-package'` instead of adding`@scope`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use NPM aliasing feature (since 6.9) for that.

In your case:

```
npm i private-package@npm:@scope/private-package
```

Would result in package being installed in `node_modules/private-package` and your tools would be able to resolve it correspondingly

See some more details in [How do I install a package with npm with a different/custom module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127054/how-do-i-install-a-package-with-npm-with-a-different-custom-module-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tsconfig's path mapping feature for this. in the "compilerOptions" section, add a "paths" section with an entry for each path map. For instance, in your case:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "private-package": ["@scope/private-package"]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if you use a bundler, it won't be aware of this mapping and you might have to configure it also.